# Updating an embedded document in mongoengine

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I have a class in mongoengine

```
class Post(EmbeddedDocument):
        uid = StringField(required=True)
        text = StringField(required=True)
        value = StringField()

class Feed(Document):
        label = StringField(required=True)
        feed_url = StringField(required=True)
        posts = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(Post))
```

I am trying to update the `Post` `EmbeddedDocument` property name text from a certain "Parent" document.
As a first step, I retrieve the Feed Document

```
model = Feed.objects(_id="....").first()
```

and then I want to update the property text of the embedded document "Post".

How can I achieve it with mongoengine?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I resolved it :)

```
Feed.objects(_id="...", posts__text="findvalue").update(set__posts__S__value="updatevalue")
```

Comment: What is 'S' in `set__posts__S__value`. Could you provide a reference to where you found this ?

Comment: For updating documents, if you don’t know the position in a list, you can use the $ positional operator. `.update(**{'inc__comments__$__votes': 1})`. However, this doesn’t map well to the syntax so you can also use a capital S instead `.update(inc__comments__S__votes=1)`.  http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/querying.html#querying-lists

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @hoangvu68's answer. Here is another example: https://gist.github.com/pingwping/92219a8a1e9d44e1dd8a

The format is:

```
MyModel.objects.find(<model-key> = <model-val>, <embedded-doc-key>__<embedded-doc-lookup-key>=<lookup-key-val>).update(set__<embedded-doc-key>__S__<embedded-doc-lookup-key> = <new-val>)
```

Note this can be split in 2 lines

```
doc = MyModel.objects.find(<model-key> = <model-val>, <embedded-doc-key>__<embedded-doc-lookup-key> = <lookup-key-val>)
doc.update(set__<embedded-doc-key>__S__<embedded-doc-lookup-key> = <new-val>)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, I think something like this will work:

```
model = Feed.objects(_id="....").first()
for post in model.posts:
    if post.text == "title":
        post.value = "placeholder for real update"
model.save()
```