# How to update/delete embeded document in ListField based on its ID mongoengine?

Tags: python, mongodb, updates, mongoengine

I have the following documents:

```
class Note(EmbeddedDocument):
    value = mongo_db.StringField(max_length=200, required=True)
    id = mongo_db.UUIDField(required=True, primary_key=True)


class Post(Document,):
    notes = mongo_db.ListField(mongo_db.EmbeddedDocumentField(Note))
```

How to write a statement that update the `value` field for a `Note` object inside the list of a `Post` object. in other words how to write something that do the following:

```
update(post_id, note_id, new_valye)
```

In similar way, how I can delete an instance of the embedded documents `Note`:

```
delete(post_id, note_id)
```

Comment: See [Updating a embedded documents in mongoengine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14170876/2313887). I meant to share the duplicate question with you earlier, but accidentally ( just briefly ) closed your question in duplicate to a completely unrelated question ( since I had multiple tabs open, felt only fair to re-open since I did not immediately have the link ). The answer is there, as well as actually being in the [mongoengine documentation](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/querying.html#querying-lists)

Comment: Thank you @NeilLunn, that is odd I could not found this question although I searched multiple times, anyway, I think this will solve my problem, but I think the part of the docs you referred to is not related.

Comment: Also @NeilLunn in this case, should I a mark the question as duplicate or delete it?

Comment: It is in the documentation "near" where I gave the link to. But you need to "scroll down" just a little bit to where it shows "updates". Note specifically you will see the MongoDB [positional `$` operator,](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) which is not valid in a MongoEngine expression ( which is based on Django "ORM" syntax ). That's the "gist" anyway. I cannot actually "force close" your question "twice" ( as mentioned earlier ). Not sure you can "self close" either, unless someone else "suggests" a similar duplicate close.

Comment: I generally don't see a need for deletion. I personally think marked duplicates with different question titles or slightly different ways of asking the same question are actually a good thing, since different people might express the same problem in different ways. So I personally like various "duplicates" with that "slightly" different way of asking. Makes it easier for others to come to the same answer.

Answer (score 2):

First I edited My `Post` Document to get the benefits of `EmbeddedDocumentListField`:

```
class Note(EmbeddedDocument):
    value = mongo_db.StringField(max_length=200, required=True)
    id = mongo_db.UUIDField(required=True, primary_key=True)


class Post(Document,):
    notes = mongo_db.EmbeddedDocumentListField(Note, required=False)
```

Then used for updating:

```
    Post.objects(
        id=post_id, 
        notes__id=note_id
    ).update(
            set__notes__S__value=my_value
    )
```

And for delete:

```
    Post.objects(id=post_id).update_one(
        pull__notes__id=note_id
    )
```

But I think, there is a problems with this approach, first update now is hard to write if you are updating many fields.

Answer (score 0):

You've got 2 ways of doing this, let's assume you want to update the second item of the list (i.e at index=1):

1) Get your document instance and use `.save()`

```
post = Post.objects().first()
post.notes[1].value = 'new_value'
post.save()
```

2) If all you need is updating a field of a document, and you know its position in the array, then you can use:

```
Post.objects.update(set__notes__1__value='new_value')
```

Comment: Thank you, but I do not know it index neither its position, I only know its ID.  I clarified it is Embeded Document not a scalar field  please read the question again.

Comment: Your Note class doesn’t have an Id field in your example

Comment: Mongoengine adds one by default.

Comment: Not in embedded fields